# How much energy can this battery store?

Tags: power, batteries

I have a 16 V lithium battery with 60 Ah.
How much energy can this battery store?

My home specifications are: 220 V mains and I have a contracted power of 6.9 kVA.

Comment: Are you intending to power your home temporarily with a battery?  Why do you think that your home specifications are relevant?  I feel like we're not understanding the question...

Comment: Powering a home at 220V AC 50 Hz from a DC battery is not trivial, regardless of how much energy the battery can store. You can't just plug the battery into your home and expect anything useful to happen. Well, unless "useful" includes a destroyed battery, a small explosion, and your house on fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The battery is 60Ah at 16V

So therefore it can provide 60A at 16V for a period of 1 Hour

Alternatively it can provide 30A at 16V for a period of 2 hours

Or 15A for 4 hours - you get the drift.  It's the number of amps it can provide in total when drained flat over a period of one hour.  The slower you drain it the less current you use, the longer it lasts.

So, for 1 hour it's 60A.

If P=VI then P=16*60

That's 960W over the period of 1 hour.

So 0.96KWh.  The length of time this will be for depends on the current you draw.

Your mains power supply has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Note that for increasing currents the internal resistance of the battery *is* relevant, in this case you might get less energy than expected. However, LiIon batteries are much more capable of delivering large currents compare to for example lead-acid batteries.

Comment: Your statement "0.48 kWh for a period of 2 hours" and similar ones are incorrect.  The battery can deliver roughly 1 kWh, whether this is spread out over 1 hour, 2 hours, or 4 hours.  It would be correct to say 0.48 kW (no hours) for 2 hours.

Comment: You're quite right.  I was forgetting the "h" in the KWh.

Answer (score 1):

The energy available from your battery is 16 V x 60 Ah = 960 Wh.

Your home 220 V isn't directly relevant to the battery.